# How can I access my Google Reader entries offline?

Tags: offline, google-reader

I am without a mobile internet plan on my smartphone, hence I am looking for a way to, whenever I'm on wifi, download my Google Reader entries for me to read offline on the road.

I don't mind installing a third-party app, even if it costs a few bucks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used two such apps, and they both work.

- https://market.android.com/details?id=com.newsrob
- https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.android.apps.reader

I suspect that Newsrob will let you save more articles offline, but am not sure.

Comment: I'll second the vote for NewsRob, particularly as it can sync either just the text or the entire article on a feed by feed basis.

Answer (score 3):

I would start with [gReader](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.noinnion.android.greader.reader), which is a very nice unofficial Google Reader app. It supports offline syncing (and can default to only sync on wifi), and multiple other options to customize it (update intervals, number of items to sync, full page/content only/content with images).

If you like it, there is a paid version [gReader Pro](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.noinnion.android.greader.readerpro) which removes advertisements and has some additional features.

Answer (score 1):

I snatched [Read it Later Pro](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.ideashower.readitlater.pro) last month during the Christmas promos on the Market. There's also a free version as well, if you want to try it without paying. You can easily download the entries from Google Reader -- select "Share" and then choose "Add to Read it Later" from Google Reader. It will then snatch the whole webpage and even apply some formatting to make it easy to read. I don't think you can do this automatically for all your feeds though -- you will have to do it separately one by one for each item.

However, if you install the Read it Later addon for Firefox on your desktop computer (not sure if there's one for Chrome), you can quickly mark all the entries you are interested in (there's a special bookmark icon in Google Reader's web interface), and they will appear later on your device when you refresh your reading list.

Additionally, there's an option in Reader to synchronize your frequently read feeds for every hour offline access, but I haven't used this in particular. There doesn't seem to be an option to control when feeds are downloaded, and which ones in particular.