# Is there a way to have Google Reader sync much more aggressively?

Tags: google-reader, rss

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I access my Google Reader entries offline?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18065/how-can-i-access-my-google-reader-entries-offline)

I commute via subway and I like to read my RSS feeds on the train, but I don't have any network connectivity at that point and I find that most of them aren't sync'd.

I'm using the official Google Reader app on ICS on a Galaxy Nexus and I have the synchronize feeds option enabled.

Is there a way to have it sync much more aggressively?  Any time I'm on Wi-Fi I'd like it to pull  down absolutely everything that is unread in Google Reader.
Ideally I'd also like it to follow any links out of the feeds to webpages and sync those as well.

Is there a way of getting Google Reader to do this? Or is there an alternative to the Google Reader app that will do it?

Comment: Tolomea, I think you might be interested in some of the answers to this previous question [How can I access my Google Reader entries offline?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18065/how-can-i-access-my-google-reader-entries-offline)

Comment: "or an alternative google reader app that will do it?"
you are probably looking for rss reader fro android.

Comment: gReader has an 'Offline Usage' option, where it will download all articles, images, and videos in your feed. I haven't used it myself, as I always have network connectivity, but it sounds like what you want. I can't find an option to follow links, though.